# checking tuple values with another file

Tags: python

Is there any way to run this code faster? 
The variable "i" is a tuple and I need to extract such entries where the first value exist in another file but the second value does not.

```
import re

with open("mr_IN.dic") as f:
    dc = list(f)

with open("DocumentList.xml") as f:
    ac = list(f)

newlist = list()
for i in ac:
    newlist.append(re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', i))

mylistf = list()
for i in newlist:
    try:
        if i[1] in dc and i[0] not in dc:
            mylistf.append(i)
    except:
        pass
```

## sample files:

```
#!wget https://github.com/shantanuo/Spell-Checker/raw/master/marathi_words_updates.oxt_FILES/autocorr/acor_mr-IN.dat

#!wget https://github.com/shantanuo/Spell-Checker/raw/master/marathi_words_updates.oxt_FILES/dicts/mr_IN.dic

#!unzip acor_mr-IN.dat
```

---

Update

I divided the list into smaller chunks and now the process seems to complete in reasonable time. I will like to know if this is correct approach and if there are any bugs in the code.

```
import re

with open("mr_IN.dic") as f:
    dc = list(f)

with open("DocumentList.xml") as f:
    ac = list(f)

newlist = list()
for i in ac:
    newlist.append(re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', i))

def divide_chunks(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i : i + n]

x = list(divide_chunks(newlist, 1000))

mylistf = list()

for y in x:
    for i in y:
        try:
            if i[1] in dc and i[0] not in dc:
                mylistf.append(i)
        except:
            pass
```

---

As suggested in the comment, here is the head of DocumentList.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> <block-list:block-list xmlns:block-list="http://openoffice.org/2001/block-list">
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="अँकरचया" block-list:name="अँकरच्या" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="अँगरी" block-list:name="अँग्री" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="अँगलस" block-list:name="अँगल्स" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="अँगलसचया" block-list:name="अँगल्सच्या" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="अँगलसचा" block-list:name="अँगल्सचा" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="अँगलसची" block-list:name="अँगल्सची" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="अँगलसनी" block-list:name="अँगल्सनी" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="अँगलो" block-list:name="अँग्लो" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="अँजिओगराफी" block-list:name="अँजिओग्राफी" />
```

And here are top 10 lines from mr_IN.dic file:

```
195482
ॐकार
अकडबाज
अकडबाजी
अकडी/AFacd
अकथित
अकबर
अकबरविरोधी
अकबराकडे
अकबराचा
```

There are 2 columns in xml file and only 1 column in dic file. The words in dic file should be present in the second column of xml file but not in the first column.

Comment: Post a small testable fragment from `DocumentList.xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I would suggest is to make `dc` a set rather than a list.
To do this, simply change `dc = list(f))` to `dc = set(split(f, '\n')))` (or 
`dc = set(split(f, '\n')[1:]))` to avoid the apparent count on the first line of mr_IN.dic being treated s a valid word).
This converts the checks to see if words are in the .dic file from a linear scan of a list to a hashed lookup in a set.

While I know it's not a problem for this (very) specific case, using a regex to extract values from XML is a Very Bad Idea.

Answer (score -2):

Why are you using `list` there when you do not need to append/remove from `dc` and `ac`.

Storing them in `tuple` will use less memory and may speed up the `in` operation

```
import re

with open("mr_IN.dic") as f:
    dc = tuple(f)

with open("DocumentList.xml") as f:
    ac = tuple(f)

newlist = tuple(re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', i) for i in ac)
def divide_chunks(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i : i + n]

x = tuple(divide_chunks(newlist, 1000))
mylistf = list()

for y in x:
    for i in y:
        try:
            if i[1] in dc and i[0] not in dc:
                mylistf.append(i)
        except:
            pass
```